# Seven wonders building a stage

Tags: 7-wonders

Can you build a stage of your wonder with resources from yellow cards?

Or only with brown and gray cards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use any resources, including those from yellow cards.

Paying for a Wonder stage is pretty much the same as paying for a structure on a card. The only difference between resources produced by yellow cards vs those produced by brown and gray cards are that yellow card resources cannot be bought by neighboring players.

From [the rules](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/c8/d6/88-7-wonders-rule.pdf):

> The resources of a city are produced by its Wonder board, its brown cards,
>   its gray cards, and some yellow cards.
>   To build a structure, a player’s city must produce the resources indicated
>   on its card.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer was helpful, and a better one doesn’t come along, please use the check mark button to mark it as the correct answer.